# Why languages do not allow multiple return values?

Tags: return-value

In languages like C which supports pointer operation, you can easily get multiple values from a procedure. But in languages like Java, it is a pain if you actually need to get multiple return values. (Using an object to wrap multiple values is bad)

In my experience, allowing multiple values returned can help improve software engineering--more flexible to organise procedure invocation, etc. But why there are so many languages that do no allow returning multiple values? I am interested to know the reasons. Thank you very much.

Comment: C doesn't have multiple return values.

Comment: Why is "using an object to wrap multiple values" bad?

Comment: It sounds not *as* bad as returning unsafe pointers to point to some random list of who knows what..  type safety for the win.

Comment: A lot of languages support tuples so the one can use these to return multiple values.

Comment: It seems you're splitting hairs. The way I'm interpreting this is returning an object or array (or in javas case an array object) does have memory overhead but it's insignificant. Multiple return values wouldn't add any measurable performance. Primarily in languages that have reliable garbage collectors.

Comment: Could it be due to how calling a function is handled in machine code where input variables are pushed on to a stack along with the address of the code to return to. Maybe always returning a single value fits well with the call stack

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I assume abusing that would trigger more allocations and correspondingly more garbages

Comment: @ILYAKhlopotov As I concern, more languages choose not to support this feature. So I wonder why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be because many of the designers of these languages have strong math backgrounds and in math a function can have multiple input parameters but (almost always) only a single output value.

Also, it keeps code understandable and standardized to some extent.

Comment: So it is more a cultural reason than some design difficulty/performance inefficiency?

Comment: Well, possibly it's to do with the limits of what the human brain can hold in memory at any point. It would be hard to keep a function returning 6 values in your head, much harder to keep track of all the variables, and dizzying trying to understand a class full of such functions.